# Disable "intelligent" anchor look up of link dialog

Tags: ckeditor

When adding a link using the default link-plugin, I want to be able to write "what-ever", e.g. `#my-id`. The link-plugin, doesn't allow this. It extracts all possible "anchors" in the current text being edited, but in my case, it is just part of a bigger "page".

Any ideas on configuration options, or do I need to write a custom plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous suggestions around on how-to configure the existing plugins and remove UI-elements etc. It does not work in current version (`4.4.3`), but thankfully you can build your own plugin and remove the existing one, quite easily. There's a good explanation of a similar plugin in the documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com

I also wrote a bit about this here: http://danielwertheim.se/2014/08/15/ckeditor-the-link-plugin-is-painfully-clever/